# PCA for dimensionality reduction of audio data

Tags: pca, spectral-analysis

I am trying to get spectrogram from audio file, using [voicebox](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/voicebox.html) tool. My input audio file is **audiofile.wav**. After spectrogram, I want to apply PCA to my spectrogram matrix, **b** (to reduce dimensionality). Is it the correct way to apply PCA?

```
[s,fs]=wavread(audiofile.wav);
[t,f,b]=spgrambw(s,fs,'gmJcw');
coeff=pca(b);
my_features  = b*coeff(:,1:50);
```

Any suggestions/hint are welcomed.

Comment: Is that Matlab code? In any case it would be more decent and promising for you to show the spectrogram - the picture or the data, and ask your question upon explaining it.

Comment: Yes, this is Matlab code. If you get the voicebox tool from the given link, and then run this code, it will automatically generate the plot for spectrogram. But, the spectrogram plot is not required for explaining PCA perhaps. My question is about correct/incorrect implementation of PCA ?

Comment: Yes. But I wanted to say this site is not Matlab forum. Why people need to download a program and run the code if the question is general statistical, as you imply?